# In Ajax Image Upload, ev.preventDefault(); not working

Tags: html, ajax, razor

It uploads the image but it redirects to UploadImage.cshtml. So apparently ev.preventDefault isn't working. Is there a solution to this without having me to go through blueimp or xhtml stuffs coz I am not ready to touch those stuffs.

```
 HTML
<form method="post" action="UploadImage.cshtml" id="imgUploadForm" class="imgUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
                        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
                        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
                        includeFormTag: false,
                        uploadText:"Upload")               
                    <input type="submit" name="buttonUpload2" value="Upload" />
                </form>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
          $('.imgUpload').submit(function (ev) {

              var frm = $(this);
              Upload(frm);
               ev.preventDefault();
          });
      });

      function Upload(frm) {
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: new FormData(frm),
              success: function (data) {
                  alert('Success');
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert('Error');
              }
          });
      }
```

Comment: I guess ev.preventDefault(); must be the first statement of method body.

Comment: I tried that. Then the form doesn't submit at all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with following Jquery code. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
          $('.imgUpload').on('submit', (function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var formData = new FormData(this);

              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: $(this).attr('action'),
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success: function (data) {
                      alert('success');
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert('error');
                  }
              });
          }));
      })
```